# Django Migrations Partially Complete

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I am using Django 1.9.7 and MySQL.

I have a migration file with multiple operations.

```
    migrations.RemoveField(
        model_name='team',
        name='country',
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='team',
        name='description',
        field=models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=200, null=True),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='team',
        name='iso_country',
        field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.DO_NOTHING, to='sys_models.Country', verbose_name='Country'),
    ),
```

Now I was under the impression, that if one of these statements failed, the entire migration would rollback as part of a larger transaction. Is that correct?

I am not seeing this behaviour, rather, I am seeing that it is possible for some DDL statements to succeed during a migration while another fails. Also, I thought the order would be applied top down, is that correct? I am not necessarily seeing this behaviour in Django migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django will run migrations inside a transaction for SQLite and PostgreSQL, as these databases that support DDL transactions. However, [MySQL does not support DDL transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/migrations/#mysql).

I assume that the operations run in order, so I'm surprised that you are seeing different behaviour, but I'm not familiar enough with the code to give a definitive answer about that.

Comment: That is what I was concerned about. Thanks for the confirmation. I worked out in the last half hour that I think the order issue was only for a migration where the first operation was a RunPython operation (Data Migration), which was not specified as atomic. So even though it failed, the DDL statements in the migration were partially processed.